# PHP Webapge not working if not coming from Home Page

Tags: php, session

PHP Webapge not working if not coming from Home Page, that means other pages are working fine if directing from Home page, but if I go directly to that page (without going from home page) it is not working, it is giving "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Home Index Page  --> www.domain/otherpage --> working fine

If directly going to the page www.domain/otherpage  --> not working

To give more context :

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    include("config/config.php");

    include("includes/functions.php");

    include "language/lang_array.php";

    include 'includes/session.php'; 

    $key = sha1(microtime());

    if(isset($_SESSION['csrf_hack']))
    unset($_SESSION['csrf_hack']);

    $_SESSION['csrf_hack']=$key;

    $_SESSION['csrf_hits']=$key;

    ...

    ....

?>
```

**Below is .htaccess file :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ ./index.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ ./redirect_page.php?permalink=$1 [L]
..
..
RewriteRule ^recent$ ./recent.php [L]
RewriteRule ^recent/(.*)$ ./recent.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Permanent page when working from home page is : domain.com/recent/1  (it is working when coming from home page, not working if directly giving url)

When I checked F12, it is giving this page status 200 : domain.com/page.php  for the page showing in url as domain.com/recent/1

Comment: This is your server related issue. Please check your installation process.

Comment: If this is server related, than nothing should work, however it is working when traverse from [[Home Index Page --> www.domain/otherpage --> working fine]]

Comment: Are you starting the session and setting the csrf prevention token on every page? Or is it being only set on the homepage? Could the lack of that token trigger a 404 error? We'd need to know what is actually happening on index.php that's not happening on *"/otherpage"* before we could even take a stab at answering this question - there's just not enough information to go on currently I'm afraid.

Comment: if you clear out the page content(an empty file), does it work. also check if there was a permanent redirect on it(try using a different browser),

Comment: I have edited my question to have more details...please check guys..